# Can I Call simultaneously from Skype from my device and pc?

Tags: skype

I have installed Skype on both my device and my PC.

Is it possible to call or accept call from both.For example I want to talk from my phone and at the same time watch the same video call from my PC.

Comment: Multitasker, eh? Why would you wanna do that? Interesting question though! :) I think it should be possible.. Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: @SurajBajaj I tried, It notify on both PC and device but when I revived call from device then on PC it display missed call and vice a verse :(

Comment: Oh.. You want to attend the SAME call on PC and phone at the same time. Because your phone doesn't have a front camera? Am I right?

Comment: @SurajBajaj Right

Comment: When you've picked up the call on one device, have you tried to initiate a "conference" from there, inviting "yourself"? Not sure if that works, it's just an idea...

Comment: if one device is already in call then can another device see that call or not?